# Comparing data from two differently formatted xml feeds

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Ive got these two feeds (in production there would be more) all about the ticket prices for an event - both of the feeds are formatted differently but essentially display the same information.

What im trying to do is compare the price attribute and find the lowest price, i know how to compare the actual prices

```
if(floatval($feed1['price']) > floatval($feed2['price']]){
    return $feed1['price'];
}
else {
    return $feed2['price'];
}
```

But what im having difficulty getting my head around is how to make sure im comparing the same event price as they are from differently formatted feeds.

ie. How can i compare the price for the London HMV concert standing price from both feeds ?

**Feed 1**

```
<type id="4558" name="Rolling Stones Concert" url="http://example1.com">
    <event id="52115351" name="HMV forum - London">
        <ticket name="Stalls" id="1354855" price="120"/>
        <ticket name="Standing" id="4654845" price="85"/>
    </event>

    <event id="52115351" name="Webley Arena - London">
        <ticket name="Stalls" id="4556147" price="110"/>
        <ticket name="Standing" id="9743466" price="95"/>
    </event>
</type>
```

**Feed 2**

```
<type id="5786" name="Rolling Stones Concert - World Tour" url="http://example2.com">
    <market id="45645634" name="London - HMV">
        <unit name="Seating" id="212770047" price="125"/>
        <unit name="Standing" id="212770046" price="80"/>
    </market>

    <market id="45645914" name="London - Wembley">
        <unit name="Seating" id="212770047" price="109"/>
        <unit name="Standing" id="212770046" price="99"/>
    </market>
</type>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something called [*Information extraction* (IE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_extraction). This is commonly done with [Natural language processing (NLP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing), e.g. you need some program that is able to analyze that

```
<type id="4558" name="Rolling Stones Concert" url="http://example1.com">
```

in the first feed represents the same as

```
<type id="5786" name="Rolling Stones Concert - World Tour" url="http://example2.com">
```

in the second feed despite the differences:

```
id="4558"                     =/=  id="5786"
name="Rolling Stones Concert" =/=  name="Rolling Stones Concert - World Tour"
<event>                       =/=  <market>
id="45645634"                 =/=  id="45645914"
name="HMV forum - London"     =/=  name="London - HMV"
<ticket>                      =/=  <unit>
name="Stalls"                 =/=  name="Stalls"
```

As you can imagine you can have difference per each new feed you will get. If you pre-analyze the data-strucutre (e.g. *<event>* is *<market>* and which attributes belong to each other, then you can run textual analysis on the values and do a similarity analysis.

Also if there are common synonyms like *Stalls* is *Seating* (or vice-versa), you can reduce the complexity upfront.

```
[feed 1] -- streamline --> [sfeed 1]\                   / [combined feed]
                     ...             X compare / align X
[feed N] -- streamline --> [sfeed N]/                   \ [unknown data]
```

Comment: thanks @harke, when you say "you need some program" is there something that might do this, as a library or plugin. Or could you point me in the direction of some further reading. Sorry if this seems like an obvious question this is the first real project ive undertaken since learning php.

Comment: @sam: This has multiple levels. I'm not good with NLP, so I can not suggest anything here (there is a great python based library for it I know). For the XML in the feeds, you can use DOMDocument and DOMXpath.  Also XSL comes to mind for some transformations run upfront (e.g. rename element and attribute names to match your preferred naming). But after this is done, the rest is either hand-made or with some NLP that has an understanding of the structure. Maybe you find someone in the field of IE that can give more suggestions.